# Javascript Variable in Url.Content

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a javascript variable called `locid` that I am trying to use as part of a URL by setting the data-url of a div as follows:

```
data-url='@Url.Content("~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/")@Model.CatItemID?LocationID=locid&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view'>
```

I know I can't just throw the locid in that string as I have done in my sample code but I just put it there to illustrate where I need my javascript variable to be.  How can I achieve this??

Comment: How are you setting the data-url?

Comment: A "GET" form will append this to the URL using the global.aspx page won't it? Are you not using a form to populate this URL

Comment: JavaScript and Serverside code do NOT run at the same time.

Comment: When and how do you set the value of the JavaScript variable? Does the variable have the value at the time that the HTML code is parsed?

Comment: @epascarello I understand there is a mix of client and server code here but there are way around that, please don't comment "can't be done" because you don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Guffa yes it does have a variable at parse time.

Comment: @mgrenier Thank you for informing me of my skill level. My SO points say I have no clue what I am talking about. Trying to have JavaScript variable being read from the client before the backend has even written that JavaScript to the page is impossible. If the variable comes from the previous page or an Ajax call, that is a different story. Since your question lacks details of where the value comes from it is hard to answer.

Comment: Right, it is a different story, so rather than just saying "can't do it" maybe you can offer a solution involving one of the methods you mention.  "Can't do it" isn't helpful.

Comment: Where did I say *"Can't do it"?* Where did anyone state *"Can't do it"* before you said that?

Comment: You implied it with your original comment, my question was how can I achieve have a javascript value in the string.  Telling my client and server code runs at different times doesn't help.  Anyways, just a suggestion for the future.  I did not mean to imply you don't know what you are doing only that it makes more sense to leave a helpful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the Javascript variable directly into attribute.
A workaround can be to reorder the parameters of your url and setting the JavaScript variable in script tag.

```
<button id="myButton" data-url='@Url.Content("~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/")@Model.CatItemID?AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view'></button>
```

I have reordered the url parameters here. The location parameter will be set by following script. Place this script just after the button element.

```
<script>
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
var url=button.getAttribute('data-url');
url+="&LocationID=" + locid;
button.setAttribute('data-url',url);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, this does set the data-url attribute, but my problem is the page loads, then the attribute is set so it doesn't update my div with the appropriate data.  How can I refresh the partial view?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is @url.content needs to be run on server, where JavaScript variable is not visible. Write an independent AJAX call to fetch content and than set content in data-url

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value in the page using `document.write`, but you can't write it out inside the tag, you have to write out the entire tag. Example:

```
<script>
document.write('<div data-url="@Url.Content("~/Catalogue_Items/ItemsActionViewPartial/")@Model.CatItemID?LocationID=' + locid + '&AsyncUpdateID=catalogue-view">');
</script>
```